# Why does hysteresis even exist in ferromagnet or Ising model?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, phase-transition, ising-model, mean-field-theory

I understand the math where mean field theory gives 2 (+ and -) self-consistent magnetization values for n-dimensional Ising model when the temperature is below the critical temperature. How does this allow a continuum of path-dependent remanent magnetization (in the part of a hysteresis where external field is 0) whose magnitude depends on how strong one has magnetically pulled the magnet to different degree of saturation?

Another way to see the apparent contradiction is to think about how many degree of freedom can a magnet has. Given zero external magnetic field, NE or NT are enough to specify the microcanonical or canonical ensemble. Now the canonical ensemble, when T is below critical, might have two well separated phase-space-traps (the + region and - region) where the barrier between the two traps are very large, so it would take a very very long time for the system to jump from one trap to another by random thermal kicks.

I understand how the two solutions from mean field theory are consistent with canonical ensemble from the above argument. However, I don't understand how remanent magnetization can be consistent with canonical ensemble. If all possible magnitude of magnetization is a continuum, not two discrete traps, then the system can always smoothly changes its magnetization by interacting with environment without abrupt jump. This means that all possible initial magnetization should converge to some final magnetization which are local minimums of free energy (like the phase-space-traps in the above paragraph). The argument from this paragraph doesn't rely on mean field nor ising model, by the way.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question: hysteresis is not an equilibrium phenomenon, but a dynamical one. You let the external magnetic field evolve and the system tries to adapt up to these external changes, but fails to do so since the field changes too fast for a new equilibrium to be reached...

Comment: @YvanVelenik Hysteresis is a equilibrium (time independent) but path-dependent phenomenon, no? If you pull a magnet very hard, then let external field go back to zero, then the magnet would have a very large remanent magnetization (for a very very long time, so it's some type of equilibrium at some time scale). If you pull a magnet very slightly, then let external field go back to zero, then the magnet would have a very small remanent magnetization (for a very very long time)

Comment: As you say, "for a very very long time", which exactly means that the system is not at equilibrium.

Comment: @YvanVelenik There are different ways time scale can be relevant. For instance, a magnet with all spin up can in principle all become spin down if we wait for an extremely extremely long time. However, we would still say the magnet with all spin up reached an equilibrium. Also suppose remenent magnetization is relevantly time dependent. What magnetization value would magnet decay toward? zero internal field or a finite value? If it always decay toward zero, then why do we call ferromagnetism a phase? The fact we do means the system is essentially at equilibrium in a relevant time scale, no?

Comment: Sure. But the state described by the Gibbs measure is the true equilibrium one, not a long-lived metastable state…